# How to remove lines from file1 that exist in file2 in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know how to remove lines from file1 that exist in file2 in C#.

I have written it in python, but how would I do it in C# (performance doesn't matter)?

The code in python looks like this:

```
file_1 = "file1.txt"
file_2 = "file2.txt"

data_1 = []
data_2 = []

with open(file_1,'r') as f:
    data_1 = f.readlines()

with open(file_2,'r') as f:
    data_2 = f.readlines()

for line in data_1:
    if line in data_2:
        print(f"Removing -> {line}")
        data_2.remove(line)

with open("output.txt",'w') as f:
    for line in data_2:
        f.write(line)
```

This is my code in C#:

```
string fileName1 = @"c:\temp\file1.txt";
string fileName2 = @"c:\temp\file2.txt";   

var allText1 = File.ReadAllLines(fileName1);
var allText2 = File.ReadAllLines(fileName2);

allText1 = allText1.Where(o => !allText2.Where(p => p == o).Any()).ToArray();
```

How do I get the lines that are removed?
Thank you!

Comment: Using Linq: `File.WriteAllLines("file1.txt", File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt").Except(File.ReadLines("file2.txt")));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
var file1 = File.ReadLines(file1path);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(file2path);
File.WriteAllLines("removed.txt", file1.Except(file2));
```

This gets the removed lines :)